# How to make sure that the re-captcha js file has been loaded before submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I have a recaptcha and a registration form.  Here's a simple version of a handler:

```
  //my_script.js

  document.getElementById("my_form").onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    grecaptcha.execute();
    var grecap_resp = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if (grecap_resp.length !== 0) {
```

And the js files:

```
<script src="my_script.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Sometimes I have to click the submit button twice. 
I believe it's caused by the fact that "recaptcha/api.js" hasn't been loaded yet when I'm clicking on the button.
As I can see, when it's been loaded, all is working well.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the docs say](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display), you can pass an onload parameter with a function name that will be called when it is loaded:

```
<script src="my_script.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaLoaded&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

And inside your `my_script.js`:

```
window.recaptchaLoaded = function() { // "window..." so is defined on the global scope
    console.log("Yay! captcha loaded"); // Here you should add your logic to show/enable the button that is disabled/hidden by default.
}
```

Comment: but I have **document.getElementById("my_form").onsubmit**

Comment: should I disable the submit button initially? and then enable it?

Comment: @Akira Exactly. Also you can add a flag, because although you add a `disabled` attribute to a button it still throws `click` events, so inside your `onsubmit` you should check for that boolean telling if the captcha was loaded or not to continue with your logic. Just create a `captchaLoaded` variable and set it to `true` when the captcha loads, for example. This is just a polyfill as almost all browsers disable `click` events on disabled elements, but seems not an standard thing so maybe there's a browser out there that still throws it on disabled elements.

Comment: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {** ----> window.recaptchaLoaded() {

Comment: Oops, the function declaration is malformed :P Edited.

Comment: now, because of a different context I suspect: **Uncaught Error: Invalid ReCAPTCHA client id: undefined** at ------> grecaptcha.execute();

Comment: @Akira You can see that now you have a `render=explicit` parameter added. That means that you have to explicitly call `render()` function, as the docs say. PRO DEV TIP: When using a library, read the docs carefully, understanding each one of the lines that you read instead of jumping around paragraphs.